# How to add a distance method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
class Point:
    """Two-Dimensional Point(x, y)"""
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        # Initialize the Point instance
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        # """Return the magnitude of vector from (0,0) to self."""
        return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Point at ({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(x={},y={})".format(self.x, self.y)
```

The class has a function called magnitude. I want to create a function which can tell the magnitude distance between two points. The following is an expected output:

```
point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(5, 7)
print(point1.magnitude)
    3.605551275463989
print(point2.magnitude)
    8.605551275463989
print(point1.distance(point2))
    5.0
```

I tried doing something like this:

```
 @classmethod
    def distance(self):
        pointmag1 = point1.magnitude
        pointmag2 = point2.magnitude
        if pointmag2 > pointmag1:
            return pointmag2 - pointmag1
        else:
            return pointmag1 - pointmag2
```

This however return an error TypeError: distance() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I also feel like I am taking an incorrect approach to this as nothing other than point1 or point2 would work. Does anyone have anything which could work better? Thanks.

EDIT: I have mmade the follwoing changes:

```
 @classmethod
    def distance(self, self2):
        pointmag1 = point1.magnitude
        pointmag2 = point2.magnitude
        if pointmag2 > pointmag1:
            return pointmag2 - pointmag1
        else:
            return pointmag1 - pointmag2
```

This however returns 4.996773991578637, instead of 5. Any way to change this?

EDIT: I made the following changes:

```
 @classmethod
    def distance(self, self2):
        pointmag1 = self.magnitude
        pointmag2 = self2.magnitude
        if pointmag2 > pointmag1:
            return pointmag2 - pointmag1
        else:
            return pointmag1 - pointmag2
```

This returns the error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'property'

Comment: Why are you making it a *property*? From the usage, surely you want a *method*?

Comment: Ah, my bad. Corrected.

Comment: You would need to pass another point to your `distance` method in order to perform the calculation against the current object.

Comment: I did this and the code returned 4.99..... instead of 5. Is there a way to change this.

Comment: you passed a point as `self2`, but you aren't referencing it

Comment: Anyone know why the code is displaying the error in the most recent edit?

Comment: Because you've defined a class method, so `self` is the class not an instance of it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe So how would I fix this?

Comment: Well if you want to operate on an instance, perhaps rethink making it a class method?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom `__sub__` method to find the distance:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  @property
  def magnitude(self):
    return math.sqrt(self.x ** 2 + self.y ** 2)
  def __sub__(self, _point):
     return pow(abs(_point.x-self.x)**2 + abs(_point.y-self.y)**2, 0.5)

point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(5, 7)
print(point2-point1)
```

Output:

```
5.0
```

Edit: `distance` implemented as a method:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def distance(self, _p2):
    return pow(abs(self.x-_p2.x)**2 + abs(self.y-_p2.y)**2, 0.5)

point1 = Point(2, 3)
point2 = Point(5, 7)
print(point1.distance(point2))
```

Comment: I don't want the code to have to use print(point2-point1). I should only have to use print(point1.distance(point2)). This is why I am trying to use a function with a classmethod

Comment: @user10200421 I think you are slightly confused as to the nature of a `classmethod`. A `classmethod` is a function that is bound to the class via a class reference. A method, however, is only accessible via an *instance* of the class. I will add an implementation of `Point.distance` as a method...

Comment: I still need to keep the magnitude function. There should be nothing changed in the other parts of the code. Also print(Point.distance(point1, point2)) does not match my output.

Comment: @user10200421 the output of `point1.distance(point2)` is `5.0`, which can be verified as correct by the Pythagorean theorem. If you need to keep the magnitude property, simply call `self.magnitude-point.magnitude` in the desired method.

Comment: So is what you are saying to replace self and _p2 with self.magnitude and point.magnitude respectively?

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding here: @Ajax1234 is talking about the **euclidean distance** between two points A and B; OP is talking about the **difference of length of the position vectors of points A and B**.

Comment: @palivek Ah, that may be it. That would explain the subtraction of the magnitude values.

Comment: Ok this finally makes sense now. I was wondering what was happening.

Comment: The difference between the directions of the position vectors is only about 2°, so, it just so happens, that those two values almost match.

Comment: The value for `point2.magnitude` as given in the question if wrong, it is 8.602325267042627, not 8.605551275463989. The difference of magnitudes could only have been equal to the distance if the two points had been aligned with the origin (and on the same side), which is not the case.